# Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: script, powershell

Good Afternoon

I have created the following powershell

```
function script{
    param (
        [string]$path = {"C:\PowerShellTest\Med Rec\1\", "C:\PowerShellTest\Med Rec\2\", "C:\PowerShellTest\Med Rec\3\"}
        )
    }

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Select-Object Directory,Name,CreationTime | Export-Csv "C:\PowerShellTest\Med Rec\text.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation

Remove-Item -Recurse -Path $path
```

when I run it I receive the following error

```
Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\PowerShellTest\New folder\Content Deleted Daily at 1AM.ps1:9 char:28
+ Remove-Item -Recurse -Path $path
+                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I'm unable to figure out why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$path` variable is outside of the scope of where `Remove-Item` is called.

Have a look at this example:

```
function script{
    $path = "hello";
    echo $path;
}
echo $path;
```

When `echo $path` is called on the last line, nothing is outputted because there has been no value placed in `$path`. However if I call `script` then `hello` is outputted, but as soon as that `script` function is done running the `$path` variable inside of the function will not be accessible any more.

To fix, define your `$path` variable where the `Remove-Item` has access to it, for example before the script function.

To see more on scope in Powershell here is Microsoft's full documentation.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it up by just creating an alias (I hope its the correct term).

> $path = "C:\PowerShellTest\MedRec\1\", "C:\PowerShellTest\MedRec\2\",
>   "C:\PowerShellTest\MedRec\3\"
>
> Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Select-Object Name,CreationTime |
>   Export-Csv "C:\PowerShellTest\MedRec\text.csv" -Force
>   -NoTypeInformation
>
> Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force